# Missing files while setting up the android notepad tutorial project

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm starting learning android development. I want to make the exercise 1:http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex1.html . So i i've setup the project as written, but i don't have the minifest and sources in it. Please see the attached screenshot[image]

I've tried to fix the project as written in tutorial, but nothing happened. What should I do to setup the project? Thanks

Comment: Do you have the AndroidManifest.xml and other files in<your-sdk-location>\samples\android-<your version>\NotePad ? They are in there, yuo can do Create Project from Existing Source

Comment: @Alex: I have these files in an archive I've downloaded from tutorial. I've already set up the project from this source according to tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just copied the files manually and it worked